# Saving user credentials securely in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, security, macos, credentials

Need to store some valuable data securely on Mac and access it with my application. How to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the KeyChain services

Comment: @iUm could you google it and find the dozens of examples out there and then ask if you're confused how they're working?  Googling "cocoa keychain example" yields 700,000+ results in under a second.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html